# Linq and Read data from another Class

Tags: c#, linq

1- I have a Data class :

```
public  class Data
  {
   public static List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee> 
   {
      new Employee {EmployeeID=1, FirstName="Garth", LastName="Schulte", Position="Trainer"}, 
      new Employee {EmployeeID=2, FirstName="James", LastName="Conrad" ,Position="Trainer"}
   };

 }
```

2- In MainWindow.xmal.cs

```
private void GetEmployeeListQuery()
{
  dynamic emps = from emp in Data.Employees
                 select emp;

  lbEmployees.DataContext = emps;
}
```

I have error when reading the select emp:

```
XamlParseException occurred
```

'The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '5'.

Please, Advise me

Comment: what does MainWindow.xaml file look like?

Comment: I don't understand, If I remove GetEmployeeListQuery , Everything will work fine .....

Comment: 1. change dynamic to var.     2.   lbEmployees.ItemSource= emps.ToList();

Comment: @Tim.Tang is right, but I think you can simplify the entire method and do `lbEmployees.DataContext = Data.Employees`

Comment: Check the inner exception of the thrown exception to find more details about why it failed in the first place.

Comment: I apply your answer Tim Tang, and your advise Vlad, but I have the same error

Comment: In the Inner exception I have : The type initializer for 'WpfApplication1.Classes.Data' threw an exception.

Comment: @KekoSha is there any special within that `initializer`? this exception is very popular in `XAML` world.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, Tim.Tang, Alejandro, King King for your advices and helps .

Comment: The inner exception of inner exception was [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.] and It was fixed .... appreciate your support , time and your help